# ServiceStack ResponseStatus Serialization

Tags: serialization, servicestack

Is it possible to make the ResponseStatus class in ServiceStack serializable, or to solve this exception in another way: "Type ServiceStack.ResponseStatus is not marked as Serializable"

Im using ServiceStack in an mono embedded system. Works perfect! Now: part of that implementation is that i Serialize the request, and send it over a Socket Connection. I let the receiver DeSerialize it, and build the response, and send it back. However, after expanding ServiceStack Dto's with a ResponseStatus property to receive possible Exceptions in clientSide, i mentioned that the ResponseStatus class in ServiceStack, is not serializable, also mentioned in the exceptions: Type ServiceStack.ResponseStatus is not marked as Serializable.

Many thanks,

Robert

Comment: What are you using that requires `[Serializable]`, i.e. What serializer are you serializing the Request with?

Comment: Im Serializing the request like so: 

        `//Serialize the object
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, netObj);`

Where netObj is offcourse the ServiceStack request.

Comment: By the way: it serializes to an byte array (byte[]) and sends that over socket, i could use something else to, something bare metal that hass as less as possible overhead...

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is one of the [slowest and largest Binary Serializers](http://theburningmonk.com/2013/09/binary-and-json-serializer-benchmarks-updated/) (it's even slower and larger than most JSON serializers), I recommend using either [ProtoBuf](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Protobuf-format) or [MsgPack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MessagePack-Format) instead.

Comment: ok, we wouldnt want that.  

can ProtoBuff or MsgPack also serialize byte arrays? That can be in the transfer object too.

(tried implementing default configuration of ProtoBuff-net, but it al it keeps giving me empty memorystream, i'll some more, offcourse..

Comment: protobuf.net perfectly serializes/deserializes byte arrays in my project for about three years. It might be better to create another question in StackOverflow about protobuf.net if you couldn't get it work with detailed information what are you trying to do and which embedded system you're using.

Comment: Yes, after some more Reading i discovered that protobuf requires my dto's to be decorated with extra DataMember attributes. I thought it was seamlessly interchangeable so i didnt figure that out right away. For now im trying MsgPack first, which is showing me promising results..